# How do I modify my delete account function to work for Google accounts?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-applications, firebase-authentication

My web app uses Firebase auth for email and password, and signing in with Google.
I have this function that is intended to delete the user's account:

```
const deleteUserAccount = () => {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(currentUser.email, reEnterPassword)).then(() => {
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).delete().then(() => {
            firebase.auth().currentUser.delete().then(() => {

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
      }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

This code only works for users that signed in with email and password, and trying to run it with an account that signed in with Google returns this error:

> code: "auth/wrong-password"
> message: "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password."

What am I doing wrong and how do I modify it to accommodate both auth types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you signed in with Google (or any other social provider) the Firebase Authentication user account does not have a password associated with it. So to sign in to that account again, the user has to sign in with the same Google credentials as before.

If you want to *also* allow the user to sign into that account with a password, you can set up a linked email+password account by [lining email address and password credentials to the user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account).